# In laravel, what happen if we define hasMany() relationship but didn't define belongsTo() relationship?

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I think (I don't really know, if I'm wrong please correct me), this is actually Many To Many relationship between Medias table and other tables (Users, Messages, Posts).

So, I am creating the middle table named Media_links to connect the Many To Many relation between these tables.

I am thinking to define the hasMany() relation for the Medias tables, but didn't want to define its belongsTo() relationship.

I didn't try anything yet. Posting this thread just to get insights first.

Comment: Please include the code, to make your problem easier understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasMany` and `belongsTo` is a `one-to-many`, NOT `many-to-many`.

about your question, you can access the relation whereever you define it, but not the inverse unless  you define it!

i.e.
if you have a Teacher and Student model

**Teacher Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Teacher extends Model {

    public function students(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

**Student Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Student extends Model {

    //Relation below not define.
    /* public function teacher(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
    } */
}


//each line below works fine, you can perform relationship related query 
$teacher->students()->create([...]); // create students relation
$teacher->students; //lazy load students relation
Teacher::with('students')->paginate(); //eager load students relation


//each line below will throw 500 error as Inverse relation is not define 
$student->teacher()->create([...]); // create teacher relation
$student->teacher; //lazy load teacher relation
Student::with('teacher')->paginate(); //eager load teacher relation
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the thorough explanation. helps me understand the laravel relationship a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really happens to your application, other than if you were to access you'r pivot table, you won't be able to call any relationships from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating pivot table you should create a belongsToMany relation , this provides you sync(), attach() methods . Otherwise you can simply create hasMany relation. What you are trying to do actually ?

Comment: I am creating many-to-many relationship between tables Bulletin and Media. The middle pivot table is Medialink. Bulletin and Media doesn't store any foreign key. Both will be stored on Medialink, bulletin_id and media_id.

And from @silver answer, I think I would define it like this:
Bulletin hasMany Medialink.
Media hasMany Medialink.
Medialink belongsTo Bulletin.
Medialink belongsTo Media.

So what about this belongsToMany relationship? Where I supposed to utilize this, and for what purpose? Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure

Comment: yeah I could read the docs even if you didn't paste the link here. thank you so much for your efforts